# How to make my iphone app icon update like the weather app icon?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application that I'm currently building that requires me to display a visual update on the application it self. example:

The weather app displays 14 degrees celcius and some clouds as its application icon. When the weather changes there is an update to the way the icon looks without having to open the weather app. The applications icon changes to reflect the update in weather. You can then open the weather app to get more information if need be.

In my application I need to have an update system like that which shows the user information without opening the application. If they would like more information they can open the application then.

I have no idea how to accomplish this task at the moment. I hope someone will be able to help or point me in the right direction. Thank you for your time.

Comment: which version of iOS are you running? The weather.app on my iPhone 4 with 4.1 doesn't do that.

Comment: seconding that the weather app doesn't update.  ever.  the calendar app, does, though, and I'd be interested to know how it does it.

Comment: The Weather app icon only changes depending on the region where an iPhone was purchased. It shows 73 degrees Fahrenheit and 23 degrees Celsius depending on which scale a region commonly uses. Other than that it isn't dynamic. I've never seen 14 anywhere — sure your device isn't jailbroken?

Comment: I'm running iOS 3.1.3 I just checked it now. My weather app says 23 degrees, and when I open the app the current weather is 23 degrees. I even checked the weather app on my blackberry and its consistent with that too. Even on the blackberry it auto-updates the image too with the current temperature and if its cloudy or not.

Comment: No my device isn't jailbroken. I mean it could be a coincidence...since everyone is saying it doesn't I guess it doesn't..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do what you are proposing. As far as I know the weather app always displays 23 degrees C. I know the iCal app displays the date but this is done using private API's only allowed for use by Apple since there is no way to do this with the public SDK.

You can however display badge numbers like the AppStore app does to display the number of available updates.

Comment: +1 Yes, Apple does this with their Calendar app using private APIs.

Comment: :( gah...I guess it doesn't. Not sure why the weather app on the iphone is different than the weather app on the blackberry..the blackberry one does it..i know that for a fact. I guess it can't be done on the iphone.

Comment: Blackberry OS is a COMPLETELY different platform that iOS. It is VERY wrong to assume that the two apps would function in the EXACT same way.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a "badge" (like unread messages on the mail app icon), but you can't change the icon of your app programmatically using the public SDK.

Comment: can anyone please guide on how to add badges to the app icons programatically.

Comment: @ArpitRaniwala `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];`

Comment: Thanks Jack. I figured this out long back, but anyways thanks for your concern.